# Solve for $t$: $ e^{-2t} + 2t = 4 $

Tags: exponential-function, lambert-w

How do we do this problem for other values of the constant, say 300 or -1000? Is there a general way to solve such questions? (Looking for a way to solve this with pen and paper.)

Comment: Have you been given some reason to believe that this *can* be solved with pen and paper?

Comment: If you draw even a rough sketch of the graphs $y=e^{-2x}$ and $y=4-2x$, it is clear there are exactly *two* solutions to $e^{-2x}+2x=4$, one with $x$ positive and one with $x$ negative.  Are you looking for both solutions or just one of them?

Comment: @BarryCipra, both.

Comment: @TheChetan, in that case, you need more than an answer that simply cites the Lambert-W function.  You also need to know how to *initiate* a Newton's method approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numerically. The exact solution involves the Product Log (Lambert-W) function.

By hand, you can use [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) or similar.

Answer (score 3):

$$e^{-2t}+2t=4$$
$$e^{-2t}=4-2t$$
$$e^{2t}=\frac{1}{4-2t}$$
$$(4-2t)e^{2t}=1$$
$$(2t-4)e^{2t-4}=-\frac{1}{e^4}$$
$$2t-4=W\left(-\frac{1}{e^4}\right)$$
$$t=\frac12W\left(-\frac{1}{e^4}\right)+2$$

This solution uses the [Lambert W-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html).

Comment: I'm curious, does this give the positive solution or the negative solution?

Comment: It gives two real solutions $t_1\approx -0.874516, t_2\approx 1.99067$, function $W$ is complex and multivalued

Comment: In cases like this, I think it helps to make explicit when "function" means "multivalued function."  (There's a reason for the "$\pm$" in the quadratic formula.)

Comment: @BarryCipra that's why I attached a link. I have never seen somebody saying "Lambert W-multivalued-function". You can clearly see it's multivalued by looking at the Riemann surfaces.